# How to convert a List[Any] in Option[List[String]]

Tags: scala, collections, type-safety

Given a List[Any], I want to convert it to a Option[List[String]]

```
def convert(ls: List[Any]) : Option[List[String]] = {
  if (ls.forall(_.getClass == classOf[String])) 
    Some(ls.map(_.asInstanceOf[String]))
  else 
    None 
}
```

Is there a better way ?

Comment: I forget if it was Effective Java or the Puzzlers where Josh Bloch asks us not to use ell for vars because it looks like one. Until I upgrade my eyeglasses, I may start a twitter campaign. :)

Comment: you're right, i've just fixed that

Comment: Actually, I think his case was the long suffix, `1l`, sorry about that; but I have the same visual parsing problem. Thx.

Comment: I don't think the `type-safety` tag is appropriate here; introspection is the opposite of safety :)

Answer (score 3):

Like:

```
scala> val bag = List("a", 1, 2.0, "b")
bag: List[Any] = List(a, 1, 2.0, b)

scala> def unbagged(vs: List[Any]): Option[List[String]] = Option(vs collect { case s: String => s}) filter (_.nonEmpty)
unbagged: (vs: List[Any])Option[List[String]]

scala> unbagged(bag)
res0: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(a, b))

scala> unbagged(List(1, 3.14))
res1: Option[List[String]] = None
```

or, addressing the use case:

```
scala> def strung(vs: List[Any]): Option[List[String]] = (Option(vs) filter (_ forall { case _: String => true case _ => false })).asInstanceOf[Option[List[String]]]
strung: (vs: List[Any])Option[List[String]]

scala> strung(bag)
res3: Option[List[String]] = None

scala> strung(List("a","b","c"))
res4: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(a, b, c))
```

Comment: As in my example, I want to be sure that all elements are String

Comment: Yeah, I guess we missed that part.

Comment: imho, `_.isInstanceOf[String]` is shorter and so more readable than `{ case _: String => true case _ => false }`

Answer (score 2):

There are already quite a few answers, but I think they're all cleverer than needed. The initial proposal in the question is not that bad, except I would replace the `getClass` test by `isInstanceOf`:

```
def convert(ls: List[Any]): Option[List[String]] = {
  if (ls.forall(_.isInstanceOf[String])) 
    Some(ls.map(_.asInstanceOf[String]))
  else 
    None 
}
```

It's functional, copies the list only once. Yes, the list is traversed twice, but typically that it still going to be faster than throwing an exception (which is usually slow -- if you really want to go that route, at least use a [`ControlThrowable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.control.ControlThrowable), which does not record the stack trace when constructed).

Besides, as @som-snytt pointed out quietly in a comment, due to erasure, you don't even need to cast all the elements inside the list. You may just as well cast the list, which, after having checked that all elements are `String`s, is just as safe as any other casts:

```
def convert(ls: List[Any]): Option[List[String]] = {
  if (ls.forall(_.isInstanceOf[String])) 
    Some(ls.asInstanceOf[List[String]])
  else 
    None 
}
```

This is simply the most efficient version, because there is no list copying at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `toString` method, which can make a String from any object. So if it's not a requirement that all elements of your original List should actually be String elements, you can do this:

```
import scala.util.Try
def convert(l: List[Any]) : Option[List[String]] = {
    Try(l.map(_.toString)).toOption
}
```

Try will return Some(x) if it succeeds and obtains a value x, or None otherwise.

If the conversion should succeed only if all elements are Strings, then we can do the conversion inside Try (at the first failure, Try will fail and hence we'll get None)

```
import scala.util.Try
def convert(l: List[Any]) : Option[List[String]] = {
    Try(l.map(_.asInstanceOf[String])).toOption
}
```

Comment: As in my example, I want to be sure that all elements are String

Comment: Then _.toString should be replaced with _.asInstanceOf[String].

Comment: Hum… i prefer to check type before rather than throwing an exception (at least for perf reason).

Comment: For performance reason first to check every element in the array, and then convert them is going to be slower, whereas failing will be just as quick with both approaches.

Comment: It's not an array, it's a list, so you don't have to rebuild it, just cast it, right? The other answers also copy it.

Comment: yeah, I like your solution tom-snytt because you avoid instantiating a new List

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use pattern matching:

```
def convert(l: List[Any]) : Option[List[String]] = {
 Try(list.collect{
   case s : String => s
   case x : Any => throw new Exception()
  }).toOption
}
```

Comment: As in my example, I want to be sure that all elements are String

Comment: I updated the answer by combining @Ashalynd solution with mine to achieve that

Comment: Hum… i prefer to check type rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: @DenisMakarenko why not use `_.asInstanceOf[String]`? This already throws an exception if the conversion fails.

Answer (score 0):

Code is a bit ugly but it works.
It doesnt use `classOf` but it uses pattern matching:

```
scala> val l1 = List("a", 1, 12.0)
l1: List[Any] = List(a, 1, 12.0)

scala> val l2 = List[Any]("a", "b", "c")
l2: List[Any] = List(a, b, c)

scala> def convert(list: List[Any]) = {
     |       list.foldLeft(Some(List()): Option[List[String]]) { (x, y) =>
     |         x match {
     |           case Some(l) =>
     |             y match {
     |               case elem: String => Some(l ::: List(elem))
     |               case _ => None
     |             }
     |           case None => None
     |         }
     |       }
     |     }
convert: (list: List[Any])Option[List[String]]

scala> convert(l1)
res12: Option[List[String]] = None

scala> convert(l2)
res13: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(a, b, c))

scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a straightforward solution using scalaz :

```
def convert(ls: List[Any]) : Option[List[String]] =
  ls.map { a => if (a.isInstanceOf[String]) Some(a.asInstanceOf[String]) else None}.sequence
```